# How to quickly mark functions library in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, idapython, python, script

I have a binary with debug information and I want to mark STL library functions with "Library function" tag as quick as possible, just by highlighting a range of functions and clicking some button instead of marking every function "Library function" by hand.
[image: list of functions]

[image]

Is there is a way to do that quick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can automate the labelling process:

```py
import idc, idautils

FUNC_LIB = 4

# Here go your selected functions
# This labels everything unless you specify the start/end args
funcs = idautils.Functions()

for ea in funcs:
    flags = idc.get_func_flags(ea) | FUNC_LIB
    idc.set_func_flags(ea, flags)
```

To label a library function we set [`FUNC_LIB`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/337.shtml) flag.

You will likely need to write a plugin for UI integration to get the selected functions. If they are in a contiguous address space you can just pass its range in `idautils.Functions(start_ea, end_ea)`.

Comment: How do I write UI integration plugin? Can you share where to read about that?

Comment: Honestly I struggle(d) to find any official docs on IDAPython plugin *development*, personally I started with Sark's [`SamplePlugin`](https://sark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging.html). I can also recommend their way of [plugin loading](https://sark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/installation.html), it's pretty convenient

Comment: @void_17 For more examples see [IDAPython's GitHub](https://github.com/idapython/src/tree/master/examples)